# NameError uninitialized constant MyWorker::MyController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq to do a simple sample worker. When a make a request to my endpoint, it finished successfully but in the worker I got the following error:

```
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant SaveMessageWorker::Message
```

I'm using:

- ruby 2.5.7
- rails 5.2.3
- sidekiq 6.0.0

This is part of my api rails project structure:

```
app
---controllers
------api
---------v1
------------messages_controller.rb
---workers
------save_message_worker.rb
config
---initializers
------sidekiq.rb
---application.rb
```

These are my files and paths:

**app/workers/save_message_worker.rb**

```
class SaveMessageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(message_list)
    # byebug
    # When I tried the below line, I got: *** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant SaveMessageWorker::Message
    message = Message.new(message: message_list)

  end
end
```

**app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb**

```
    def multiple_concurrent_workers
        begin

            SaveMessageWorker.perform_async("Hello World!")
            return (render json: {status: "success", data:"processed successfully"})

        rescue => exception
            logger.error CONTROLLER_NAME + ': An error happened in method multiple_concurrent_workers: ' + exception.to_json
            return (render json: {status: "error", message: exception})
        end
    end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  
  devise_for :users 
    namespace :api, defaults: { format: "json" } do
      namespace :v1 do

          resources :messages do
            collection do
              post :multiple_concurrent_workers
            end
          end

      end
    end

end
```

**config/initializers/sidekiq.rb**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://' + Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:host].to_s + ':' +Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:port].to_s + '/' + Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:database].to_s }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://' + Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:host].to_s + ':' +Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:port].to_s + '/' + Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:redis][:database].to_s }
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module IbeenDev
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
    config.log_level = :error
    
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")

    config.api_only = true
    Koala.config.api_version = 'v2.0'

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

  end
end
```

There was an opened issued in the github project, but [author](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3779#issuecomment-370664321) said that this is not an exactly sidekiq problem.

Can anyone help me to find the solution? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: And where is `Message` defined? Is that a model in the `models` folder? Please show that class' code and tell how that file is called and where it is located.

Comment: Solved. There was a really fool error in the Message model definition, ```class Messages < ApplicationRecord``` instead of ```class Message < ApplicationRecord```